# How to connect to a Grakn Server running on a GCP VM instance

Tags: java, remote-access, remote-server, vaticle-typedb

I'm trying to connect to a Grakn Server running on a GCP VM instance. I have read the related post in the discussion forum. One of the replies suggests to do the following on the server side:

```
Edit ./conf/main/grakn.properties:

storage.hostname=EXTERNAL.ip.v4.address

Edit ./conf/cassandra/cassandra.yaml:

seeds: "EXTERNAL.ip.v4.address"
broadcast_address: EXTERNAL.ip.v4.address
listen_address: INTERNAL.ip.v4.address
rpc_address: INTERNAL.ip.v4.address
```

Access it from the Java API:
GraknSession session = Grakn.session(“EXTERNAL.ip.v4.address”, keySpaceName);

What i have interpreted from this, for my specific case, is the following:
-Replace EXTERNAL.ip.v4.address with the External IP of my VM instance
-Replace INTERNAL.ip.v4.address with the Internal IP of my VM instance

When i start the server i get this exception cause (I think this is the root cause):

Caused by:

```
com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.PoolTimeoutException: 
PoolTimeoutException: [host=104.197.131.17(104.197.131.17):9160, 
latency=10000(10000), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection         
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.SimpleHostConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SimpleHostConnectionPool.java:231)
```

What am i missing?
Do i have to add firewall rules?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

To access Grakn remotely using the Java API, you need to open the following ports on the GCP and Linux VM firewall (eg. iptables):

- 4567
- 9160

Make sure you are able to access those from the client machine.